# Spring Security 403 even with correct username and password , i can't authenticate

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to build a spring boot rest API with JWT role-based authentication, I'm stuck at the login part in spring security.

I'm currently using spring boot, spring data JPA (hibernate under the hood ), and Oracle 11g database.

All the tables get created and I can sign up but can't login.

WebSecurityConfig.java

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.*;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.*;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.*;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;



@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new UserDetailsServiceImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

        return authProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/users/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/roles").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                // this disables session creation on Spring Security
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    }

}
```

UserDetails.java

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class UserDetails implements org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails {
    private User user;

    @Autowired
    private UsersRepository usersRepository;


    public UserDetails(UsersRepository usersRepository) {
        this.usersRepository = usersRepository;
    }

    public UserDetails(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        Set<Role> roles = user.getRoles();
        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Role role : roles) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
        }

        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getUsername();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return user.isEnabled();
    }

}
```

UserDetailsServiceImpl.java

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private UsersRepository usersRepository;


    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = usersRepository.getUserByUsername(username);
        System.out.println("Found user in repo : "+user.getUsername()+" "+user.getPassword()+" "+user.getRoles());
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Could not find user");
        }

        return new UserDetails(user);
    }
}
```

JWTAuthenticationFilter.java

```
import com.auth0.jwt.JWT;
import com.bte.ifrs_server.entities.User;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

import static com.auth0.jwt.algorithms.Algorithm.HMAC512;

public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public JWTAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                                HttpServletResponse res) throws AuthenticationException {
        System.out.println("Attempting authentication");
        try {
            User creds = new ObjectMapper()
                    .readValue(req.getInputStream(), User.class);


            return authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            creds.getUsername(),
                            creds.getPassword(),
                            new ArrayList<>())
            );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                            HttpServletResponse res,
                                            FilterChain chain,
                                            Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {

        System.out.println("Successfull Auth !!");
        String token = JWT.create()
                .withSubject(((User) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername())
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + EXPIRATION_TIME))
                .sign(HMAC512(SECRET.getBytes()));
        //Printing the access token into the response
        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
        res.setContentType("application/json");
        res.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        //Creating access token object to return it as a response
        AccessToken accessToken=new AccessToken(HEADER_STRING,TOKEN_PREFIX,token);

        //Set the access token as a JSON response body
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String access_token=gson.toJson(accessToken);
        out.print(access_token);
        out.flush();

        //Adding the access token to response header
        res.addHeader(HEADER_STRING, TOKEN_PREFIX + token);
    }
}
```

JWTAuthorizationFilter.java

```
import com.auth0.jwt.JWT;
import com.auth0.jwt.algorithms.Algorithm;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;



public class JWTAuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {


    public JWTAuthorizationFilter(AuthenticationManager authManager) {
        super(authManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req,
                                    HttpServletResponse res,
                                    FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String header = req.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);

        if (header == null || !header.startsWith(TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
            return;
        }

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = getAuthentication(req);

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String token = request.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);
        if (token != null) {
            // parse the token.
            String user = JWT.require(Algorithm.HMAC512(SECRET.getBytes()))
                    .build()
                    .verify(token.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, ""))
                    .getSubject();

            if (user != null) {
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, new ArrayList<>());
            }
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

AccessToken.java

```
 public class AccessToken {
        String header,prefix,value;

        public AccessToken(String header, String prefix, String value) {
            this.header = header;
            this.prefix = prefix;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
```

SecurityConstants.java

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class SecurityConstants {
    public static final String SECRET = "SecretKeyToGenJWTs";
    public static final long EXPIRATION_TIME = 864_000_000; // 10 days
    public static final String TOKEN_PREFIX = "Bearer ";
    public static final String HEADER_STRING = "Authorization";
    public static final String SIGN_UP_URL = "/users/sign-up";
    public static final List<String> PUBLIC_ROUTES = Arrays.asList("/users/sign-up" , "/users/login" , "/roles/**");
}
```

Role.java

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "role_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "id_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="id_generator", sequenceName = "role_id_sequence",allocationSize = 1)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

User.java

```
import java.util.*;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "id_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="id_generator", sequenceName = "user_id_sequence",allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private boolean enabled;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
    )
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}
```

and the main app:
IfrsServerApplication.java

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@EnableJpaRepositories
@SpringBootApplication
public class IfrsServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(IfrsServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

The code compiles and the server runs I can signup but authentication returns 403 after attempting to login ('/login').

Any Help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's a 403... (HTTP 403 is returned when the client is _not permitted access to the resource despite providing authentication_ such as insufficient permissions of the authenticated account). So you may be authenticated, but not authorized... I see you use `hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")`... maybe that should be `hasRole("ADMIN")`, but that is just a guess...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've shared quite a bit of code, so there may be other issues here, but one that I'll point out is that in your `JWTAuthorizationFilter`, you are not granting any authorities to the user:

```java
return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, new ArrayList<>());
```

The last parameter is what authorities the user has.

Configurations like:

```
.antMatchers("/roles").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
```

will always return a 403 in that case.

The first solution I'd recommend is using Spring Security's built-in support for JWTs instead of rolling your own. There's [a JWT login sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/master/servlet/spring-boot/java/jwt/login) that looks quite similar to what you are trying to achieve.

Alternatively, you can try changing how you are calling that constructor so that you grant a list of authorities (like `new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ADMIN")`). The downside here is that you'll have a lot more code to maintain.